# jQuery - TableSorter custom parser not working

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Here is my custom parser:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "customParser",
    is: function (stringValue) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (stringValue) {
        var stringValueParts = stringValue.split("-");
        var numericPartOfStringValue = parseInt(stringValueParts[2]);
        return numericPartOfStringValue ;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

stringValue will have values like:

- ABC-DE-1
- ABC-DE-10
- ABC-DE-100
- ABC-DE-101
- ABC-DE-1000

Here is the code where I set-up the tablesorter and added the custom sort parser:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dataTable").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            3: {
                sorter: 'customParser'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I did add a console.log(numericPartOfStringValue) and all of the numbers were written out to the console so it seems like the parser is doing what it should be doing.

**So what do I want to happen?**

I want my values to be sorted on the numeric part of the string as below:

- ABC-DE-1
- ABC-DE-10
- ABC-DE-100
- ABC-DE-101
- ABC-DE-1000

**What is actually happening?**

The values are being sorted in this way:

- ABC-DE-1
- ABC-DE-10
- ABC-DE-100
- ABC-DE-1000
- ABC-DE-101

**What else did I try?**

I added the following to my html but it didn't make a difference:

```
<th class="{sorter: 'CustomParser'}">
    String Value Column
</th>
```

**And finally:**

Here is an example value from the table cell:

```
<td>
    <span class="badge">ABC-DE-1</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Are you using DataTables or tablesorter? If you want to keep using tablesorter, try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which uses an alphanumeric sort by default. So no need for a special parser in your case.

Comment: I was using both, datatables for the paging and tablesorter for the sorting. The issue was that my custom tablesorter parser was not working with the datatable paging. I don't know why I was not using the datatables sorting so I have switched my code to use the datatables sorting now. I implemented a custom parser in datatables and everything is working now.

Therefore, this question is redundant now. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 3):

Its working, you just need to set the default sort order.  I used [`sortList.`](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-list.html) which is an array of tuples which contain the th-index and the order (asc=0, desc=1).

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/GXX7W/):

```
 $("#dataTable").tablesorter({
     sortList: [[0,0]],   
     headers: {
            0: {
                sorter: 'customParser'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle to show it working. Your fiddle works without the "sortList: [[0,0]]" when you click on the column header, it just doesn't sort on load. I don't really understand why my code is not working. So this has me stumped. I am using paging so I thought that maybe this might be causing an issue. When I remove the paging my original code is working fine so now I suspect it's something in the paging that is preventing this from working.

I am using datatables.net for paging and filtering, I have no idea why I am not using datatables.net for the sorting as well. I am off to check.

Comment: Ok, I did not figure out why the tablesorter was not working with datatables.net paging but I have managed to use datatables.net sorting instead of tablesorter.

Thanks for confirming that it wasn't my code that was the issue.

Comment: @careywalker update your post above and I can try and help you out.